# Use component HTML in other component as part of the page

Tags: html, angular

I have a component with some feature and its html say a.component.ts

```
class AComponent {
  ....
}
```

a.component.html

```
<div>
  Bunch of HTML with many logic
</div>
```

Now I have extended above a component in b.component.ts

```
class BComponent extends AComponent {
  Have some it's own code
}
```

b.component.html

```
<div>
  // Include A HTML
</div>
<div>
   B's html code goes here
</div>
```

I don't want to use the A component directly here like `<a-component></a-component>` because in this case **A Component code will be called twice**.

Any Idea how to how only the html of a component in other component as part of the page without calling the component.

Comment: It is a bad practice to extends components, you can move all common logic to service and inject service to both components. So why do you need inheritance?

Comment: You mean inheriting is bad practice? It is the fundamental of OOPs, anyway thanks for your comment.

Comment: Yesm in Angular it is bad practice, in backend is it good approach of OOP